# Wrapping Checkbox on Checked with .is() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code snippet. Why might the `.is()` not be working on wrapping only the checked checkboxes?

```js
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
  $("input:checkbox").is(":checked").wrap("<span class='check-wrap-sapn'></div>");
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Check the console, think about the error, get the jQuery API documentation and check the functions you're using

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  Just posting code is not going to get you answers.

Comment: whats your question?  is there an error?

Comment: I am sorry but I typed a paragraph abot quetion not sure why not is here

Answer (score 3):

`.is()` returns a boolean so it is not chainable. You want `.has()`

Now the issue you have is if the user unchecks it, it still will be wrapped and if they check it again, you will have multiple wrapped elements. You probably should just wrap the element to start and toggle the class on the parent element.

```js
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
  $(this).closest("label").toggleClass("checked", this.checked);
}).trigger("change");
```

```css
label.checked {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation of [`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

So the return value of `.is` is a *boolean*. But you're trying to call a jQuery method on it.

Additionally, you're repeating your DOM query within the event handler, and so will act on **all** matching elements, not just the one that relates to the event.

And your wrapper starts out as a div but ends as a span. Might want to be consistent about that.

And I suspect `check-wrap-sapn` was meant to be `check-wrap-span`.

If I'm guessing correctly at your goal, then:

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function()  {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.is(":checked")) {
    $this.wrap("<span class='check-wrap-span'></span>");
  } else {
    $this.unwrap();
  }
});
```

Or:

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).wrap("<span class='check-wrap-span'></span>");
  } else {
    $(this).unwrap();
  }
});
```

**Live Example**:

```js
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).wrap("<span class='check-wrap-span'></span>");
  } else {
    $(this).unwrap();
  }
});
```

```css
.check-wrap-span {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

But this is something that would be much better handled with styling the CSS, via the `:checked` pseudo-class, provided the styling in question can be applied to checkboxes. If it can't, I'd advocate always having the wrapper span, but toggling a class on it:

**Live Example**:

```js
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
  $(this.parentNode).toggleClass("check-wrap-span", this.checked);
});
```

```css
.check-wrap-span {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<span><input type="checkbox"></span>
<span><input type="checkbox"></span>
<span><input type="checkbox"></span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good thinking about unwrapping when unchecked +1

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `$(this)` inside the event handler to check if the checkbox is checked
2. `is` returns boolean result, use `is()` in `if` and if the checkbox is checked, then wrap it.

```js
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.is(":checked"))
    $this.wrap("<span class='red'></div>");
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Best to store $(this) in a variable instead of selecting it twice.

Comment: @taxicala Yes since it is used more than once, caching will be better for performance, updated